# How to seperate a debit and credit in a cursor for loop in plsql

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql

I have a `cursor for loop` include credit and debit amount of my daily transaction account, and I want to show them respectively.

```
DECLARE

v_debit := 0;
v_credit := 0;

CURSOR c_acct_rec is 
select bk.acctname, bk.bsb, bk.accountnr, bk.value, bk.code
from mybank_tbl bk
r_acct_rec c_acct_rec%ROWTYPE;

FOR r_acct_rec in c_acct_rec LOOP
   if r_acct_rec.code = 'dr' then
      v_debit := show_debit;     
   else
      v_credit := v_credit + r_acct_rec;
   end if;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_credit || v_debit); 

END LOOP;
END;
```

This part of the SQL query from the above is showing all the debit and credit values.

```
+-----------------+
| value  | code | |
+-----------------+
| | 12   |  dr  | |
| |  5   |  dr  | |
| |  7   |  dr  | |
| | 33   |  dr  | |
| | 16   |  dr  | |
| | 1000 |  cr  | |
+-----------------+
```

The problem I found because they are in the cursor loop, it will populate all value in one column like below

```
+-------+--------+
| Debit | Credit |
+-------+--------+
|    12 |        |
|     5 |        |
|     7 |        |
|    33 |        |
|    16 |        |
|  1000 |        |
+-------+--------+
```

The if/else statement can't control it to show all row records.

```
+-------+--------+
| Debit | Credit |
+-------+--------+
|    12 |    0   |
|     5 |    0   |
|     7 |    0   |
|    33 |    0   |
|    16 |    0   |
|  1000 |    0   |
|  1000 |  1000  |
+-------+--------+
```

Is that a way to separate it using a stored procedure or separate the row from the account value (r_acct_rec.value) to check to get this expected outcome?

```
+-------+--------+
| Debit | Credit |
+-------+--------+
|    12 |        |
|     5 |        |
|     7 |        |
|    33 |        |
|    16 |        |
|       |  1000  |
+-------+--------+
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand the question.  It would be helpful if you posted a piece of working code that produced the output you're seeing.  In your second piece of code, you're using `==` which isn't a valid operator, you have a stray `and` before the `then`, I'm guessing that `dr` is supposed to be the string `'dr'`, is `show_debit` really a function that takes no parameters and returns a value?  If so, what is that supposed to do.  And then you're adding `v_acct_rec`, a pseudorecord, to `v_credit` which I assume is a local numeric variable which doesn't make sense.

Comment: If I assume all those things are artifacts that you've accidentally introduced in posting the question, my vague guess is that you forgot to re-initialize `v_credit` and `v_debit` on each iteration of the loop to NULL if you want one of the two to be NULL and the other to be non-NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables. You need to populate one and blank the other, depending on the value of `code`. Use pad functions in the display to align the output nicely.

```
DECLARE

    v_debit number := 0;
    v_credit number := 0;

    CURSOR c_acct_rec is 
    select bk.acctname, bk.bsb, bk.accountnr, bk.value, bk.code
    from mybank_tbl bk
    r_acct_rec c_acct_rec%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('credit',10)|| ' | ' || rpad('debit',10)); 

    FOR r_acct_rec in c_acct_rec LOOP
       if r_acct_rec.code = 'dr' then
          v_credit := null;
          v_debit := r_acct_rec.value;     
       else
          v_credit := r_acct_rec.value;
          v_debit := null;
       end if;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lpad(v_credit,10)|| ' | ' || lpad(v_debit,10)); 

    END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make the transformation from code-value into separate values in the query and eliminate the code for determining them.

```
declare
    cursor c_acct_rec is 
        select bk.acctname
             , bk.bsb
             , bk.accountnr
             , case when bk.code = 'dr' then bk.value else null end as debit
             , case when bk.code = 'cr' then bk.value else null end as credit         
        from mybank_tbl bk;

    r_acct_rec c_acct_rec%rowtype;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad('credit',10)|| ' | ' || rpad('debit',10)); 
    for r_acct_rec in c_acct_rec loop
        dbms_output.put_line(lpad(r_acct_rec.credit,10)|| ' | ' || lpad(r_acct_rec.debit,10)); 
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be met in SQL only, it does not require PL/SQL.

```
select 
bk.acctname, 
bk.bsb, 
bk.accountnr, 
bk.value, 
bk.code,
case 
    when bk.code = 'dr' then
    bk.value
end as debit,
case 
    when bk.code = 'cr' then
    bk.value
end as credit
from mybank_tbl bk
```